# Rating specific comments in PHP and MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

So I've got a system in place to post comments to a page, where they are all called from the database and displayed on the page. Each comment has a value called "rating" which is defaulted to 1, and each comment has up and down arrows to the left of it for rating up and rating down which would increase and decrease the rating respectively. Now, I've figured out how to increase and decrease the numbers, but the way I have it, all posts' ratings increase at the same time, regardless of which post I rate.

This is my "rateup" function:

```
$(function () {
        $('#rateup').click(function() {
            var request = $.ajax( {
                type: "POST",
                url: "rateup.php"                               
            });
            request.done(function( msg ) {
                return;
                });
            request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {

            });
            location.reload();
        });
    });
```

This is my rateup.php file:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "db_posts";
$tablename = "posts";

// Connection to database
$connection=mysqli_connect("$servername","$username","$password","$dbname");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'NOT_OK';
    //echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// Increasing the current value with 1
mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE $tablename SET rating = (rating + 1)");

mysqli_close($connection);

echo 'OK';   
?>
```

I know that the reason it's incrementing all posts' ratings is because I'm not specifying which post to increment, and that's what I need help with. How do I specify which post is rated when the links to the left of said post are clicked?

The links are echoed like so:

```
echo " <a class='noStyle' id='rateup' href='index.php'>&#9660;</a>";
```

It's just a unicode up arrow that's echoed with the post.

Thanks!

Comment: db query needs a `WHERE` clause based on unique identifier for row. Try along lines of `<a href='index.php?id=". $row['id']."'>&#9660;</a>`. Then that is `$_GET['id']` in php. Make sure to validate it then pass to `WHERE`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which link you are clicking and send that through the form.
You can add a data-* tag to your links to do this:

```
echo " <a class='noStyle' id='rateup' href='index.php' data-id='".$commentID."'>&#9660;</a>";
```

Then you can get that value when you submit the form and send it as data:

```
$(function () {
    $('.rateup').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        $.ajax( {
            type: "POST",
            data: "id=" + id,
            url: "rateup.php"                               
        });
        location.reload();
    });
});
```

Then you can retrieve this through the form:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "db_posts";
$tablename = "posts";

// Connection to database
$connection=mysqli_connect("$servername","$username","$password","$dbname");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'NOT_OK';
    //echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$id = $_POST['id'];

// Increasing the current value with 1
mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE $tablename SET rating = (rating + 1) WHERE commentID = '".$id."'");

mysqli_close($connection);

echo 'OK';   
?>
```

Comment: I just tried this and nothing at all happened. No errors or anything, but nothing was rated at all.

Comment: It is most likely because the value for commentID that you sent through was blank. Check your output source code to make sure the attribute is working. For example, it should be something like <a data-id='5'></a>

Comment: You're right, it's coming out blank. I'm not sure why though, I have it set right in the code. The database row is just called 'id' I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it though.

Comment: Change the variable to from $commentID to $row['id'], or whatever gets the id out of the database.

Comment: I'm super rusty at this. It's telling me it's expecting a ',' or a ';' somewhere on this line, but I'm not seeing where it's missing: 

`echo "<br><div id='messageBar'><b><a class='noStyle' id='rateup' href='index.php' data-id=' "$row['id']" '>&#9650;</a> ";`

Comment: You need a "." to separate variables from text. It should be data-id=' " . $row['id'] . " '

Comment: Alright, looks like the values aren't coming out blank anymore. However, clicking the links still does nothing. I want to confirm that this is correct:

`mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE $tablename SET rating = (rating + 1) WHERE $row['id']= ' ".$id." ' ");`

Comment: No, your statement should be: mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE $tablename SET rating = (rating + 1) WHERE id = ' ".$id." ' ");

Comment: Fixed that, but it continues to not work. Maybe my function isn't right? I'm not sure. I haven't done this kind of stuff since high school.

Comment: I'm assuming that the problem is in the jQuery. After you set the variable id, do alert(id), so you can verify the data is going through.

Comment: Did that, when I click the up arrow on the first post it alerts '50' which is the id of the first post, however none of the other posts alert anything at all when their arrows are clicked.

Comment: One of the problems is the id attribute is unique, you cannot use it for multiple tags. Change them to class="rateup" and it should work

Comment: And for the jQuery:  $('.rateup').click(function() { }

Comment: Changed " id='rateup' " to " class='rateup' " in the <a> tags and changed the line of the jQuery you mentioned and nothing changed.

Comment: Okay just realized the <a> tag had two classes now because of the CSS class, so I removed the CSS class and now it alerts the ID every time, but the rating doesn't change.

Comment: Send your form like this: $.ajax( {
            type: "POST",
            data: "id=" + id,
            url: "rateup.php"                               
        }); This works for me.

Comment: That's exactly what I have already `var request = $.ajax( {
     type: "POST",
     data: "id=" + id,
     url: "rateup.php"                               
    });`

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. I saw your edits now and that was not quite what I had. Though, I changed my code to match your edits and it's still not working. I'm really not sure why. You said it works for you, so you tested it?